# SQL Server Compare data and replaced together

Tags: sql, sql-server, design-patterns, substring, patindex

I have two string as below:

```
 ***ABCABCABCABCABC***
 BBBTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCCC
```

I want to replace * position only from below string

So results could be:

```
 BBBABCABCABCABCABCCCC
 BBBTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCCC
```

Is there any way to have elegant solution to using SQL Server function?

I already did it using below.

```
 DECLARE @Value1=PATINDEX('%[A,C,G,T]%', '***ABCABCABCABCABC***')
 Select SUBSTRING('BBBTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTBBB', 0, @Value1)
 ....
```

But this is required many if else.

I want to know is there any simple way to replace it or not.

Comment: No, there is not an elegant solution.  There are solutions, but I can't think of anything that would be considered "elegant".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

**[DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/368177)**

```
DECLARE
   @String1 NVARCHAR(100) = '***ABCABCABCABCABC***',
   @String2 NVARCHAR(100) = 'BBBTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCCC';

DECLARE @new_string NVARCHAR(100) = NULL;

;WITH nums AS
(
  SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.number) AS N
  FROM master..spt_values t1 
  CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2
), string_1 AS
(
  SELECT N, letter
  FROM nums
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUBSTRING(@String1, nums.N, 1) WHERE nums.N <= LEN(@String1)) 
    AS t(letter)
), string_2 AS
(
  SELECT N, letter
  FROM nums
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUBSTRING(@String2, nums.N, 1) WHERE nums.N <= LEN(@String2)) 
   AS t(letter)
), new_string AS
(
  SELECT Letter = CASE WHEN s1.Letter <> '*' THEN s1.Letter ELSE s2.Letter END,
         s1.N
  FROM string_1 s1
  LEFT JOIN string_2 s2
    ON s1.N = s2.N
)
SELECT @new_string = (SELECT '' + ISNULL(Letter, '')
                      FROM new_string
                      ORDER BY N ASC
                      FOR XML PATH(''));
                            
SELECT @new_string
UNION ALL
SELECT @String2;
```

1. Generate numbers (you can use any method)
2. Split strings one and two by letters
3. Generate new string, replacing `*` with corresponding letters
4. Join letters together

*Remark: You can combine all of this in one query, but I split it for readability.*

Feel free to wrap it to function to make it **elegant**:

```
[dbo].[udf_merge_string](@string NVARCHAR(100), @string2 NVARCHAR(100)) ...
```